# Ya no veo el script ejecutado en la consola del navegador

Tags: jquery

Tengo este codigo en jquery y siempre uso la consola para ver el funcionamiento de mi aplicacion.

Pero ahora no hace efecto en la pagina y en la consola no aparecen los script .php que estan dentro de las peticiones ajax.
Osea estaba agregando funciones y de repente me ocurrio.

```js
var content;
var id;
var nombre;
var marca;
var precio;
var alicuota;
$(document).ready(function() {
listar();
$("#cat").focus();
listarcategorias();
listarsubcategorias();
function filtrarsubcat(idcat){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
//recorro subcategorias
    for(var i = 0; i < subcat.length; i++) {
      //si esta el idcat
    if (subcat[i].idcategoria === idcat){
        //lo meto en el array
        filtrado.push(subcat[i]);}
        
        }
        $("#subcat").empty();
     
        for(var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
          var newRow ="<option id="+filtrado[i].idsubcat+">"+filtrado[i].subcategoria+"</option>";
                  
          $(newRow).appendTo("#subcat");
        
       
    }
}   
    

function listarsubcategorias(){
   
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/getsubcategorias.php",
          dataType: 'json',
            

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
      
       subcat=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 
                            var newRow ="<option id="+data[i].idsubcat+">"+data[i].subcategoria+"</option>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#subcat");
                         
                
                       
        
                             
       
    
               
            }
           
        }
});}

$("#cat").change(function(){
    var idcat=$(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    if (idcat){
       filtrarsubcat(idcat);
       filtrarcat(idcat);
    }
});
function filtrarcat(idcat){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].idcategoria===idcat) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      $("#resultado tbody").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].subcategoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + filtrado[i].aliiva + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");                 
       }
 
 
  
}};
$("#subcat").change(function(){
   
    var idsubcat=$(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    if (idsubcat){
       filtrarprodsubcat(idsubcat);
    
    }
});
function listarcategorias(){
    accion="listadocat";
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/getcategoria.php",
            data: {"accion":accion}, 
            dataType: 'json',

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
                
       console.log(data);
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               
        
                var newRow ="<option id="+data[i].idcategoria+">"+data[i].categoria+"</option>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#cat");                 
       
    
               
            }
           
        }
});}
var nombreBusqueda;

 $("#nombre").keyup(function() {
            
        nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
        filtrar(nombreBusqueda);
    }
);
  var id;
  var nombre;
  var marca;
  var producto;
    var precio;
// Detectar clic en una fila
$("#resultado tbody").click(function(event) {
  $("tr").click(function(event) {
 id = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
 nombre = $(this).children('td').eq(1).text();
 marca = $(this).children('td').eq(2).text();
 precio = $(this).children('td').eq(4).text();
 alicuota = $(this).children('td').eq(5).text();
 producto = nombre + "  " +  marca;
$("#nombreselec").val(producto);

});
 

$("#Agregar").click(function(event){
  var cantidad=$("#CANTIDAD").val();
  var nombreart=$("#nombreselec").val();
  if (nombreart===""){
    alert("seleccione un articulo");
 }
  if (cantidad!==""){
    var accion = "agregar";
 
    $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/procesoFactA.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id,"cantidad":cantidad,"nombre":nombre,"marca":marca,"precio":precio,"alicuota":alicuota}, 
         

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           
        }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});

    
  } else{
    alert("ingrese cantidad");
  }
});

});

function filtrarprodsubcat(idsubcat){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].idsubcat===idsubcat) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      $("#resultado tbody").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].subcategoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].aliiva + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");                 
       }
 
 
  
}};
function filtrar(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      $("#resultado tbody").empty();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].subcategoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].aliiva + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+filtrado[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                  
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");                 
       }
 
 
  
}};
function listar(){

    tipofiltro="todos";
  $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/php/filtroP.php",
            data: { "tf": tipofiltro}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
     content=data;
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].subcategoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].aliiva + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+data[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");                 
       
    
               
            }
        
  

        }  
}).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});
};
  

});
```

Osea debe estar mal estructurado el archivo? Por otro lado las funciones van fuera del ready?

Comment: te fijastes si el tab o pestaña de red de la consola esta activado?, te fijastes si en la pestaña de la consola en sus filtros tienes habilitado ver las peticiones?

Comment: Definitivamente, habia un error, pero en la pestaña de red si aparecio..Gracias